# questions on a continuous, injective, surjective

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous, injective, surjective.

Question 1, if $f$ is open or closed, then does $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Question 2, if $f$ is open or closed, then does $f^{-1}$ open or closed?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** A function $h:A\to B$ is continuous if and only if $h^{-1}U$ is open (closed) in $A$ for every open (closed) $U$ in $B$.

1. Note that $(f^{-1})^{-1}U=fU$ for every $U\subseteq X$.
2. Use the fact that $f$ is continuous to derive the conclusion. The assumption of $f$ being also open or closed is not relevant.

Comment: 1 second faster!

Comment: @Pambos. Yeah I saw that :)

Comment: @ThomasE.If $f$ continuous, injective, surjective + open (or closed), then $X=Y$?

Comment: @John. Those conditions imply that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, but not necessarily that $X=Y$. For e.g. the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ are homeomorphic by the function $x\mapsto 2x$, which is continuous; open; surjective; and injective; but $(0,1)\neq (0,2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A function $g:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous $\iff \forall U\subseteq Y$ open $g^{-1}(U)\subseteq X $ is open $ \iff \forall K\subseteq Y$ closed $g^{-1}(K)\subseteq X$ is closed.